# Why isn't my break not going back to my label?

Tags: java, loops, break, continue

So for school I am trying to make an Asynchronous chat program with 2 classes; the server and the client. Basically the client connects to the server, and writes text until the string  or  are entered. If  is entered then the client listens for text and the server gets to send instead. If  is entered the client disconnects, and the server resets the connections and waits for client to connect again. I am trying to solve these requirements with some do..whiles, and then a continue label to reset the connections. Right now if the client sends  the connection resets but the server just stops the build instead of returning to my startConnections label. Here is my code for my server which I am using the break in:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    startConnections:
    {
        System.out.println("RESET TEST");

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(12345, 100);


            System.out.println("Waiting for client");
            connection = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Connected");

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            output.flush();

            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            do {

                do {
                    messageIn = (String) input.readObject();

                    System.out.println("CLIENT SAYS: " + messageIn);
                } while ((!messageIn.equals("<OVER>")) & (!messageIn.equals("<OUT>")));
                if (messageIn.equals("<OUT>")) {
                    break startConnections;
                }

                do {
                    System.out.print("RESPONSE: ");

                    keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                    messageOut = keyboardInput.nextLine();

                    output.writeObject(messageOut);

                } while (!messageOut.equals("<OVER>"));

            } while (!messageOut.equals("<OUT>"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Oops SERVER! : " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not *meant* to go back to your label. It isn't a `goto`. It is meant to break out of that loop. Are you looking for `continue`?

Answer (score 1):

It works [as it should](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated) statement.

So the next executed statement after the `break` call is what comes after the loop labeled with `startConnections`

To get the behavior you want, you need to use `continue`:

```
continue startConnections;
```

> A labeled continue statement skips the current iteration of an outer loop marked with the given label.

Comment: OK so it doesn't actually go back to the start of the label? I never used labels so I think I just mis understood what they do. I guess I can just wrap the code at the start in another loop? edit: nvm I will try with continue